# Search cell above keyword to copy and replace cell below another keyword

Tags: vba, excel

I need help to create a VBA code for Excel that will make my everyday work easier.
I need to find the keyword "Submissions" and take the cell right above it, copy the cell.

Paste the cell below another keyword "Totals". And loop it such that it goes on finding the next "Submissions" and "Totals"

I'm not taught in VBA.
I usually just copy and paste codes I've found on the net.
My code may be messy and all over the place

This code I have is not working, it uses the cell found above the first keyword "Submissions" and paste on cells below all the "Totals", which is not what I want. I want the value on cell (a date format: 1/2/2018) above first "Submissions" on cell below first "Totals" and value on cell above second "Submissions" on cell below second "Totals" and continue. They are all in the same column (column A)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim x
  Dim y

  For x = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row To ActiveCell.Row Step -1
    For y = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row To ActiveCell.Row Step -1
      If Cells(x, 1) = "Submissions" Then 
        If Cells(y, 1) = "Totals" Then
          ActiveCell(x - 1, 1).Copy ActiveCell(y + 1, 1)
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8fS0.png)

Not sure how and why, I got it working with this

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim x
Dim y
Dim y_start
Dim x_start

    y_start = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 x_start = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = x_start To ActiveCell.Row Step -1
    If Cells(x, 1) = "Submissions" Then
            For y = x_start To ActiveCell.Row Step -1

                If Cells(y, 1).Value = "Totals" Then

             ActiveCell(x - 1, 1).Copy ActiveCell(y + 1, 1)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                x_start = x + 2
                  Exit For
                End If
        Next
        End If
    Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Record a macro and check the code generated.

Comment: I've tried, but the recording macro function only shows the cells position. not based on the keyword criteria

Comment: Some images of sample data (before and after) might describe better what you need to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

To get a good answer please give a better description of what you are trying to do. ie how your data is formatted which is usually necessary to understand how it could be done.
However I will try to help you out. To do this you will need to know a few of the basic structures in vba. The first is the For or While loops:

```
For i = 1 to 10
    'Do this code
Next i

Do While condition = True
    'Do this code
Loop
```

This for loop above will run your code 10 times so you will want to use this if you know exactly how many cells you want to check. Use the while loop if you don't know how many cells you will need to check as it runs until the condition stops being true.

You will also need to know how to reference cells which will follow a format similar to below. Range is referenced like a formula in a workbook and Cells takes an argument of (row, column) beginning from the top left corner. If you are within the same sheet you can drop the Sheets("Sheet1"). off of the front and use Range("A1").value or Cells(1, 1).value instead.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

You can use these to either take the value out of a cell or to change the cell value.

Finally you will need to know the if statement which compares two inputs by the arguments =, >, <, <> with that last one meaning not equal

```
If arg1 = arg2 Then
    'This runs if the condition is true
Else
    'This runs if the condition is false
    'The Else is optional
End If
```

Putting these together you should be able to make a code work for you.

EDIT

I see what you are trying to do now. You need an Exit For to break out of the Totals loop. I modified your code slightly

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim x
    Dim y

    Dim y_start
    y_start = 1

    For x = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Cells(x, 1) = "Submissions" Then
            For y = y_start To Cells(y_start, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                If Cells(y, 1) = "Totals" Then
                    Cells(x - 1, 1).Copy Cells(y + 1, 1)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    y_start = y + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Value on cell is a date format. And the keywords are all in the same column (column A)

Comment: Good answer but, you shouldn't mention (and teach) others to _drop the Sheets("Sheet1"). off_ - this is one of the most common issues because code that doesn't qualify the sheet (and workbook) explicitly will use the Activesheet, which is where most of the problems arise. Also, to be more useful your answer should be in the form of an entire Sub or Function (like in the question)

Comment: somehow nothing is reacting when I run this code, nothing is being copied

Comment: I found the problem. The references that were being used before assumed that the cursor was in a certain spot when you began the macro. I edited it to loop over the entire column. If it doesn't start in cell A1 you will need to change that reference.

Comment: strangely there's no reaction either after tweaks to the range